# Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: Unknown problem:

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, signature, multisignature

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? My contract function is working fine for some accounts, then not for other's. It completely random also, sometimes it's one account sometimes it's another.

Using web3 integration with react from truffle-react-box, any help or explanation is appreciated. It's obviously something to do with signing the transaction that I know, but how can I avoid it is what I'm asking.

After this error is faced once with that account any further tx's from that account are reverted.

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: Unknown problem: {"from":"0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de","to":"0xf25186b5081ff5ce73482ad761db0eb0d25abfbf","value":"0x22b1c8c1227a0000","data":"0xb587448f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004592a454899b200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022b1c8c1227a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000886c98b760004458000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","gas":"0x575184","gasPrice":"0x77359400","nonce":"0x2"} {code: -32603, message: "Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: Unknown problem: {"f…"0x575184","gasPrice":"0x77359400","nonce":"0x2"}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out using the provided truffle mnemonic to create a new MetaMask account was causing the error, better to create a fresh one and then import the default accounts.

```
candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat
```